# How to increase the height of any particular slide in MS Powerpoint 2007?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007

How to increase the height of any particular slide in MS Powerpoint 2007?

If I paste/add any image which has longer height than slides's height than powerpoint paste images with reduced zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only option here is to resize the image. You can't make slides bigger or smaller, other than zooming in/out, but that is in editor view.

Use the scroll wheel or bars to find the edge of the picture and attempt to resize it, or, zoom out by changing the zoom in the toolbar or holding CTRL and scrolling down on the scroll wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Design** tab, and select **Page Setup**. Using this window, you can edit the width and height of your slides.

[image]

Comment: OK. Will check this tomorrow.